# I want to write a equation in the following manner, but there seem to be some error

Tags: equations, align, subequations

[image]

code:

```
\begin{equation}
X_{n+1} = [aX_{n} + c] \quad \textrm{mod m} 
\end{equation}
\begin{center}
    \textrm{m, the Modulus (m > 0),} \\
    \textrm{a, the Multiplier (0 < a $\leq$ m),} \\
    \textrm{c, the increment (0 $\leq$ c < m),} \\
    \textrm{X_n}\textrm{, the starting value} \\
\end{center}
```

Comment: PS: I am trying to make the below 4 lines left aligned with the main equation. but there seem to be errors, hence using "center" command for it.

Comment: You need to take care that you use math macros in math environments and non-math macros in non-math environments. `\textrm{}` cannot be used in an math environment, while `_`, `>` and `<` can only be used inside a math environment. So, you need to replace `\textrm{mod m}` by `\mod m`. Then, you shoud remove all those `\textrm{}`s in the `center` environment and instread put everything that is a math expression between `$`...`$`, such as `$a$, the Multiplier ($0 < a \leq m$)` etc. This should solve most of your problems.

Comment: Thank you, it works now.

Comment: @JasperHabicht; Why not `\textrm`within a math environment? One may have to add a short explanation  in an equation.

Comment: @Bernard You are right, it may be OK to use `\textrm` within a math environment. I thought that there is only `\text`. Sorry! Still, in the example above, I would choose the predefined macro `\mod`.

Comment: I agree with you. Probably the O.P. wasn't aware of this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a  way to do it, with a tabular nested in an `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 & X_{n+1} = [aX_{n} + c] \mod m \\[0.5ex]
 &\rlap{\upshape \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
   $ m $, the Modulus ($ m > 0 $), \\
    $a$, the Multiplier ($ 0 < a \leq m $), \\
   $c$, the increment ($ 0 \leq c < m $), \\
   $X_n$, the starting value
\end{tabular}}\notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]